# Can't establish connection by port 22 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2

What happeed:
    There is a server with Windows Server 2012 R2, and I need to using ssh on it. So I installed OpenSSH 7.8 on it. But when I tried connect from other server, connect was refused.

What I did:
 1. Close the Windows Firewall.
 2. Check the network devices if any limit between two server.
 3. Execute command "telnet 127.0.0.1 22" on server, and it said "connect failed".
 4. Because I operation this server by remote desktop, so the network adapter and it's driver is ok.

What I want:
    Base on above operation, this problem looks not caused by fire wall or outside devices. So, what sould I do to solve this problem?

Thank you all!

Comment: Did you allow that port thru the windows firewall on the server?

Comment: Because I need useing remote desktop and this server couldn't connection Internet. So I closed the Windows firewall after I installed the OS at once.

Comment: Define „closed“

Comment: Point 3 seems conclusive: either your SSH service isn't running, or it isn't bound to that port.

Comment: open path  control panel > system & security > Windows firewall > custom setting > disable Windows firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few pointers:

1. First check if your ssh server is running:

   netstat -ant or netstat -an

   This needs to show your SSH process running on port 22.
2. Turn The windows firewall back on and allow the exception for port 22.
3. Check from a host that has nmap/telnet to see if you can access port 22.